# Export and Import settings of Plasma5

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma-5

Is there a way of exporting and importing Plasma5 settings like settings for the taskbar, dophlin, shortcuts and so on and import them for a new user or on a new installation?

Answer (score 0):

Configuration files are stored in `~/.config` and `~/.kde/share` (for KDE apps). If you want to get the configuration for a specific program, look for a file containing the program's name and ending in `rc` or `.conf`. Some examples are

- `~/.config/dolphinrc`
- `~/.kde/share/config/amarokrc`
- `~/.config/kde.org/plasmashell.conf`

Be careful, though, as some programs may store their configurations in unexpected places. Some configurations also may not work if the new user has a different name from the old one (for example, one line in my `amarokrc` is `1=./home/andrew/Music` - this would be different depending on the username) or if they are a different person than the old user (`~/.config/emaildefaults` stores the user's preferred email address).

Some programs may even have several configuration files containing different data! Picmi, for example, uses `~/.config/picmirc` to store high scores, and `~/.config/picmi/picmi.conf` to store the previous window position.

If this is just to transfer a single user's settings to the new computer, you could likely get away without changing anything (I copied my entire user folder over when I switched computers, because I had the same username on both machines), but otherwise you'll need to be careful about what files you keep and what files you leave behind.